# error solving two coupled second order differential equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, physics, differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following differential equations on matlab. (They are the equations obtained from the yang-mills-higgs lagrangian for the hoofy polyakov monopole ansatz). This is my function file. I have two variables h and k and their derivatives w.r.t to a variable t. My x(1)=h, x(2)=k, x(3)=dh\dt, x(4)=dk\dt. All the functions have initial value 0.

```
    function xprime = monopole( t,x )
    %UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
    %   Detailed explanation goes here

    xprime(1)=x(3);
    xprime(2)=x(4);
    xprime(4)=(1/(t.^2)).*((x(2).^2)-1).*x(2) + 4.*(x(1).^2).*x(2);
    xprime(3)=(2/(t.^2)).*(x(2).^2).*x(1)-(1-(x(1)).^2).*x(1)-(2/t).*x(3);
    xprime=xprime(:);




end
```

Now when I run the following code
    >

```
> t0=0;
    >> tf=10;
    >> x0=[0 0 0 0];
    >> [t,s]=ode45(@monopole,[t0,tf],x0);
    >> plot(t,s(:,1));
```

I am not getting anything. The graph window appears but it doesnt contain anything. This equations are supposed to have solutions. The dotted curves is what one should get with the curve starting from 1 is k, and from 0 is h.

[image]

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

When this happens the first thing you should do is look at the values in the t and s vectors. In this case s(1,1) contains 0, and s(:,2:end) are all NaN. Hence nothing on the plot.

As to why this is happening, a few thoughts

1. Are you sure that your definition of `monopole` is correct?
2. Why are you showing a plot where k(0) = 1, but passing it an initial condition of k=0?
3. Why are you using h^prime(0) = 0 initial conditions, but in the plot it looks like h^prime(0) has a non-zero slope?
4. The term with the 1./t^2 sure looks suspicious; just think about it, at the very first step you are going to divide 0 by 0, hence NaN. Perhaps the ode solver is having a hard time with this, and another solver would work better (note: I have very little experience with ODE solvers, so take this with a big grain of salt).

Finally, to make sure you really understand how to use the ODE solver, why not start  with a very simple ODE where you know the exact answer (i.e. harmonic oscillator).

Comment: Hey , thanks for the answer. I just realised, I have my initial conditions wrong. Thanks a lot for pointing out, in haste probably i mistyped it, and i tried to go over it again and again but couldnt pinpoint what is wrong because I never thought the error would be there. I will change the conditions, and try another ode solver. I will get back to you if i doesnt work.

Comment: Hey, i changed the initial condition for x(2) which should actually be 1, but the graph gave zeroes, so i tried playing around with the initial conditions for dh/dt and dk\dt,(i.e. x(3) and x(4)) which I have not been given. I am getting non trivial graphs, but again not the graph I wanted. Am I missing something, or can the initial conditions for the first derivatives be found from the equation?

Comment: To my eye, the graphs looks like it has IC of h(0) = 0, h'(0) = 1/2, k(0) = 1, k'(0) = 0. So this would be x(1) = 0, x(2) = 1, x(3) = 1/2, x(4) = 0, correct? Since I'm not familiar with the 'yang-mills-higgs lagrangian for the hoofy polyakov monopole ansatz', I don't think I have any advice to add other than what I said in my answer. Well, one other thing: rewrite `monopole` from scratch (perhaps changing the meanings of the variables) to check that you haven't done anything wrong there.